# Laravel 5: Use implode() with Eloquent the right way

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `checkbox` group and want to insert them in my database as `val`(1,2,3).

here is my blade

```
<div class="form-group">
     @foreach($extra as $ext)
        <div class="checkbox">
           <label>
          {{ Form::checkbox('extra_services[]', $ext->id, null, ['class' => 'checkbox']) }}
          {!! $ext->title !!}
           </label>
        </div>
     @endforeach
</div>
```

and here is controller

```
    $temp->currency = $request->currency;
    $temp->implode($request->extra_services, ',');
    $temp->save();
```

I got

> strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

what is the right way to insert my checkbox values into my db as (1, 2, 3)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need change

`$temp->implode($request->extra_services, ',');`

to

`$temp->extra_services = implode(',', $request->extra_services);`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you want to assign the value to `$temp->extra_services`. The code then should be

```
$temp->extra_services = collect($request->extra_services)->implode(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

$locations = implode(', ',Arr::pluck($business->locations, 'name'));

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).